# Denied warranty claim on carbon bike due to impact?

Tags: frames, carbon, replacement

I saw a little crack on the bottom section top tube of bike which is a kestrel talon. I took it the bike shop to see if it was covered under warranty. I have fallen once or twice from the bike but I have not been in any accident at all.

The bike shop took pictures and sent it to Advanced Sports and they asked him to send the frame to them. Once they took a look at the frame they denied warranty claim saying that the issue is caused by some kinda impact.

They do offer a replacement frame for a discounted price which is like 500$.

The question is should I get the frame back and get it fixed or get a replacement frame only?
Update: went ahead and ordered a replacement.

Comment: Did you choose another of the same brand or did you choose another brand ?

Comment: @Criggie same frame different graphics....

Comment: If it goes badly again, please vote with your feet and change brands.  You're tacitly supporting and agreeing with their stated position that it was impact damage.

Comment: @Criggie you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd not take this "statement from authority" as an absolute truth.  Ask them to prove its impact damage.

Depending on your location, there may be ombudsman services or small claims courts where you can pursue them for "failure to honour warranty contract"

- If the frame is replaced, they will keep the old one and you look after your new one.
- If the claim is rejected, you should contact a carbon fibre specialist and have it checked out.  If a repair seems worth doing and affordable, go ahead.
- Otherwise don't be a sucker to buy the "discount" frame.  Consider another brand who does honour their warranty.  It'll happen again.

Comment: He's in the USA, so it's very likely that the legally required warranty is only "caveat emptor".